# FME - Exploding Series of Attributes to Features for Each Combination

Tags: fme-form, table

Given a unique identifier attribute (TYPE below), there needs to be the combination for each comparison between the identifier and (n) value attributes to be written as a new feature. See the example below:

**Input Table:**

[image: Input Table]

**Output Table:**

[image: Output Table]

Is this possible to do in FME?

Comment: AttributePivoter http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/attributepivoter.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also built the AttributeExploder for this type of purpose.  But since you want the "type" kept, you'd need to ask it to explode but also keep the original attributes on each of the "exploded" features that are output. Check out the attached for inspiration. I did get the table you want output shown in my Inspector after running. There are some additional "fme_*" attributes exploded which you could discard.

Hope this helps.

[image: Workspace that Blows It Up Real Good]